# Can I do a Scala method that takes a simple generic type that have generic type?

Tags: scala, generics

I want to make a function in my object so that it is instantiated in any part of my code, but my function must be generic and it receives parameters that I already defined as generic. My object:

```
object GeneralService {
  def getRecordsLastUpdate[
    A <: BaseElemem, 
    E <: BaseModel[F <: BaseElemem, D <: BaseEntity[A], T <: BaseTable[A]]
  ](date: Timestamp): Future[Seq[A]] = E.getElementForSend(date)
}
```

My BaseModel :

```
trait BaseModel[E <: BaseElemem, D <: BaseEntity[E], T <: BaseTable[E]] {
        def getElementForSend(l: Timestamp): Future[Seq[E]] = db.run(table.filter(_.lastUpdate > l).result)
}
```

In my code:

[image]

I already have functions with parameters of type: BaseElement and they work well, but of BaseModel not since they receive parameters

does not recognize BaseModel in my function. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Yes, you can do generic functions with generic parameters. Do you have any other questions? Did you want to ask anything about the attached code?
2) Where is the method `getElementForSend` supposed to come from? 3) Your `getRecordsLastUpdate` is supposed to return something with `A`, but the RHS mentions only `E`, and `E` is in no way connected to `A`. 3) What kind of language construct is `E.foo(bar)` even supposed to be? | Your question is completely unclear. Please fix at least the listed issues.

Comment: Please don't use images to show code.

Comment: You are asking about generic functions, but functions cannot be generic in Scala. Also, your code is showing a method, not a function. Can you clear up that confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is to specify these generic types one-by-one instead of inside another definition. Like so:

```
object GeneralService {
  def getRecordsLastUpdate[
    A <: BaseElemem, 
    F <: BaseElemem,
    D <: BaseEntity[A],
    T <: BaseTable[A],
    E <: BaseModel[F, D, T]
  ](date: Timestamp): Future[Seq[A]] = E.getElementForSend(date)
}
```

Or, if you don't actually care about some of those types, you might do, for instance:

```
object GeneralService {
  def getRecordsLastUpdate[
    A <: BaseElemem, 
    E <: BaseModel[_, _, _]
  ](date: Timestamp): Future[Seq[A]] = E.getElementForSend(date)
}
```

Also, `E.getElementForSend(date)` is invalid syntax- you can't call a method on a type, only an instance of that type.

Comment: Thanks! the syntax for the general parameters of the function works perfectly as you put it, now call an function of E I can not do it, I'll look for another way Thank you!